# RelativeLayout animate() method not firing

Tags: android, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` that I'm trying to animate with the code below:

```
view.animate().translationX(-1080).setDuration(200);
```

Basicaly the view should go off the screen to the left. If I change the `translationX(1080)` parameter to a positive value the view is animated to the right.

Have I not understood how the `animate()` and `translationX(int)` method work?

Comment: The animation is being started only if the translationX parameter is positive

Answer (score 1):

Please check screenwidth value make sure that its not 0 and make sure that its in pixel

Comment: how screen width could be negative, how are you getting that screen width

Comment: its the devices width that Im using its an integer value of -1080

Answer (score 0):

you may try this for animate your view

```
int a = -1080;
int duration = 200;
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(a, 0, 0, 0);
anim.setDuration(duration);

anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
{
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)rlMain.getLayoutParams();
        params.topMargin += 10; // Amount to move Down
        params.leftMargin += 10; // Amount to move Right
        rlMain.setLayoutParams(params);
}
});

rlMain.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Im trying to move the view not fade it

Comment: I have the problem is somehow with the negative value

Comment: the -1080 has to be a variable

Comment: I have tested this no my device the code working fine with variable ..after update code

Comment: what you want ... ? please would you like to mention the description for your requirement ?